# Testing OpenGL compatibility

Tags: opengl

I'm having concern about my code which was developed with OpenGL 3.3 hardware level support in mind. However I would like to use certain extesntions, and want to make sure they all require OpenGL version 3.3 or lower before I use them. Let take an example, [ARB_draw_indirect](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/draw_indirect.txt). It says that "OpengGL 3.1 is required", however there is [according to this document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At5QLa2ZAYZBdHFLbEtvOHF5S1NobWJFbmpDUHZSWWc&usp=sharing) which seems to also state that the extension is not available in 3.3. The problem here is that both of my dev machines have hardware support for 4.5, which means that everything works, including those features that requires OpenGL 4.x. So I would like to know how can I test 3.3 compatibility without having to purchase 3.3 class graphic card? To put it simple, my dev hardware is too powerful compare to what I plan to support, and thus not sure how to test my code.

EDIT: On a related note, there is EXT_direct_state_access extension, and DSA is in the OpenGL 4.5 core profile. The main difference is EXT suffix in function names. Suppose that I want to stick to OpenGL 3.3 support, should I use function names with EXT suffix? Example: TextureParameteriEXT( ) vs TextureParameteri( )

Comment: For a  first question: Create core 3.3 context. You will  be limited to 3.3 functionality. For second: unclear what you're asking. Obviously `EXT*` functions are only available when respective extension is available in the implementation, and functions you want to use without `EXT` are only available on implementations with 4.x (and they are free to not provide the `EXT*` version, and they don't most times). You should provide separate code paths for different "feature levels" (as they call it in DirectX).

Comment: For the second part, I asked specifically about EXT_direct_state_access, which is widely available on almost all implementations. One example is should TextureParameteriEXT( ) and TextureParameteri( ), which one should I use? Separate code paths is exactly my concern, as I want to stick to only one unified code path

Comment: @Drop Many OpenGL implementations will always give you a context with the highest version that is available. So if you ask for a 3.3 context, you might get a context that supports 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the versions, it sounds like you're mixing up two aspects. To make this clearer, there are typically two main steps in adding new functionality to OpenGL:

1. An extension is defined. It can be used on implementations that support the specific extension. When you use it, the entry points will have `EXT`, `ARB`, or a vendor name as part of their name.
2. For some extensions, it is later decided that they should become core functionality. Sometimes the new core functionality might be exactly like the extension, sometimes it might get tweaked while being promoted to core functionality. Once it's core functionality, the entry points will look like any other OpenGL entry point, without any special pre-/postfix.

Now, if you look at an extension specification, and you see:

> OpengGL 3.1 is required

This refers to step 1 above. Somebody defined an extension, and says that the extension is based on OpenGL 3.1. So any OpenGL implementation that supports at least version 3.1 **can** provide support for this extension. It is still an extension, which means it's optional. To use it, you need to:

- Have at least OpenGL 3.1.
- Test that the extension is available.
- Use the `EXT`/`ARB`/vendor prefix/postfix in the entry points.

It most definitely does **not** mean that the functionality is part of core OpenGL 3.1.

If somebody says:

> DSA is in the OpenGL 4.5 core profile

This refers to step 2 above. The functionality originally defined in the DSA extension was promoted to core functionality in 4.5. To use this core functionality, you need to:

- Have at least OpenGL 4.5.
- **Not** use the `EXT`/`ARB`/vendor prefix/postfix in the entry points.

Once an extension is core functionality in the OpenGL version you are targeting, this is typically what you should do. So in this case, you do not use the prefix/postfix anymore.

Making sure that you're only using functionality from your targeted OpenGL version is not as simple as you'd think. Creating an OpenGL context of this version is often not sufficient. Implementations can, and often do, give you a context that supports a higher version. Your specified version is treated as a minimum, not as the exact version you get.

If you work on a platform that requires extension loaders (Windows, Linux), I believe there are some extension loaders that let you generate header files for a specific OpenGL version. That's probably you best option. Other than that, you need to check the specs to verify that the calls you want to use are available in the version you're targeting.